# Fabric.js - text decoration looks not exactly right

Tags: fabricjs

This image is from [kitchensink](http://fabricjs.com/kitchensink), and the problems are :

1. Line through doesn't exactly at right place (see the left text at top)
2. When it's italic with background color, the text is a bit out of its background (see the left text at top)
3. Underline is a bit far from text, or can we adjust its distance?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing an **experimental feature** — `fabric.IText` — that's currently in development. It allows to edit text inline and supports partial formatting.

1. The problem with line-through is [known](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/issues/945).
2. Underline being far probably has to do with stretched text. When I load kitchensink it looks good.
3. Background and italics is an interesting one. I just checked google docs and there's the same problem there:

[image]

Comment: Got it, just hoping fabric.js getting better. Yes I feel underline is a bit misplaced in stretched Text. I don't know much about HTML5 Canvas API, so don't know if somehow because of its limitation. So if there are any wrong mood from my question, I am sorry for that. Thanks. Fabric.js is very nice one I think.